# What is the difference between Debug.Write and Trace.Write?

Tags: .net

What is the difference between `Debug.Write()` and `Trace.Write()`? When should each be used?

Comment: This question probably came from here, if anyone's interested: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/what-great-net-developers-ought-to-know-more-net-interview-questions

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In the typical release build configuration, the `Debug` class is disabled and does nothing. `Trace`, however, can still be used in the release. You would typically use `Debug.Write` for stuff you only need when debugging and which is too verbose for production.

Here's a good article on `Debug, Trace` etc: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/trace/debugtreatise.aspx

However, I'm more inclined to use logging libraries like **log4net** which can be reconfigured on the fly. So you can still turn on full logging in production if you're investigating problems with your application.

Answer (score 13):

[`Debug.Write`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.write(loband).aspx) is only effective on builds where the `DEBUG` flag is defined, while [`Trace.Write`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.write(loband).aspx) is only effective when the `TRACE` flag is defined.

Answer (score 2):

One difference too is, that **DEBUG is defined** (by default) **only in Debug** project build configuration and **TRACE is defined** (again by default) **in Debug and Release** project build configuration. (At least in VS 2015.)

You can change default behavior for each project in project properties.

**Debug:**
[image]

**Release:**
[image]